# Test if a link is Opengraph friendly

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I have a website that basically extract the opengraph metadatas from links in a database.. and now I have to create a verify code to check if the link that the user is sending through a submit box to my website database is opengraph friendly. I need to do a kind of a test in the link and see if it has at least the meta property="og:image" on its source code, and then avoid the submission of links that will not work properly. I’m also using a recaptcha to avoid spammers and I was thinking that I could use the same verify code of the recaptcha to do this opengraph test. Anyone have any idea of how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solve that out some months ago, if someone end up here thats how I did it:

Instead of trying to search for the metadata, I just used the `$array` again with all the opengraph elements and checked if I really got something there

```
require_once('OpenGraph.php');
$v = $_POST["submitted_by_user"];    
$graph = OpenGraph::fetch($v);

if ($graph === false) {

die ('NO OPENGRAPH')

}

else {

// submit to database

}
```

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

> I need to do a kind of a test in the link and see if it has at least the meta property="og:image" on its source code

Well, should be obvious that this means actually reading the source code of that page, and look for the meta element.

Wether you want to read just the first x bytes of the ressource (that’s what FB does AFAIK), and then perform a string/regexp search, or if you want to use an HTML parser on it and look for it in the DOM, that’s your decision to make … the first is maybe a little more error-prone, while the second means more complexity.